# Deep learning to predict the temperature

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, prediction, temperature

Let's say I have a training data. I train the model for whole number temperatures like 1,2,3,4,5 degrees. Basically, Those output temperatures are the labels. How can I predict the values that lies between two temperatures like 2.5 degree. It is not possible to train for every values of temperature. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if you've trained to a discrete classification, but you want continuous output.  Switch your algorithm to do regression, rather than classification.

Another possibility is to harness your last-layer output to interpolate.  Use the weights given to the top choice and its strongest adjacent choice.  For instance, if your classification gives

```
1  .01
2  .05
3  .56
4  .24
5  .14
```

... you would interpolate with 56 parts `3` and 24 parts `4`, to get `3.7 degrees` as your output.

Does that help?

**UPDATE**

(1) *how can I switch to regression from classification?*

This is far too broad for Stack Overflow; you need to do your research first.  The difference between the two is not trivial.  You would need to ask a specific question, which requires posting a new question that includes your current code and your work toward making the switch.

(2) *while I am predicting values from output, how do I know that I am looking for 3.7 degrees ... ?*

While you're predicting, you don't *know*; that would have been an issue for training.  The example I gave is just an illustration of a possible result.  I invented an example, since you gave no details on your data.

(3) *whose parts should I select?*

I recommended that you take the top guess (the one that would have been your integer-value classification), and the more probable of the adjacent values.  In my example, `3` is the top guess.  You look at `2` and `4`, and see the `4` is more likely than `2`, so use `4` for the interpolation's other endpoint.

Comment: Yes, your answer is close. I was thinking about doing interpolation, but how about its accuracy? And how can I switch to regression from classification? Also, while I am predicting values from output, how do I know that I am looking for 3.7 degrees or whose parts should I select?  @Prune

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Answer 3 is perfect. For 1, I need to learn more. 2  is related to 3